# Render range of ages in a Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Hi I am working on condition to render age between a range of numbers in a dropdown.
So my condition is that minimum value of age shown in dropdown will be User age + 5 years and maximum will be 85 years or (age + 55 years), whichever is lower, till now i have implemented the following, but somehow when i pass the range in Array.from() i am not getting the desired output.
so for example if user age is 26, the list in dropdown will start from 26 + 5 i.e 31 which i am getting but the last element will be 85 years but with my logic it is getting started from  32. So the final list value is more than 100 which is incorrect, it should be till 85 only.

```
function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("2");

  useEffect(() => {
    let userAge = 26;
    let newList = Array.from(Array(calu(userAge)), (v, i) => {
      return {
        label: `${i + 1 + userAge + 4} years`,
        value: i + 1 + userAge + 4
      };
    });
    setValues(newList);
  }, []);

  const calu = (currAge) => {
    let lastValue = 85;
    if (currAge + 55 >= lastValue) {
      return lastValue;
    }
    return currAge + 55;
  };

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="agent-simple">Agent</InputLabel>
      <Select
        value={selected}
        onChange={handleChange}
        inputProps={{
          name: "agent",
          id: "age-simple"
        }}
      >
        {values.map((value, index) => {
          return <MenuItem value={value.value}>{value.label}</MenuItem>;
        })}
      </Select>
    
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

the overall condition i am not able to satisfy, i am missing some logic here.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Array.from(Array(calu(userAge) - userAge), (v, i) => {
```

`calu` calculates the maximum age, e.g. 85. But then, the Array you iterate over should not have 85 elements, but only 59 (85-26), so you must subtract the `userAge` when calculating the desired length of the Array